# In an Avalonia treeview, how to keep keyboard focus on an item after a treeview item refresh

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I have an Avalonia treeview, and e.g. a key binding on the items that triggers a refresh command for that particular item, or a subscription to the KeyUp event, as shown in the code snippet further on. But after the refresh command has been executed, the selected item in the treeview has lost keyboard focus. I'm looking to a solution on how to restore the keyboard focus.

I see that the TreeviewItem itself is Focusable, however item.Focus() returns false, and the item does not have the focus indeed.

I do a lookup of the TreeviewItem as follows:

```
                TreeView.GetObservable(KeyUpEvent)
                    .Where(evt => evt.Key == Key.F5)
                    .Subscribe(evt =>
                    {
                        ViewModel?.RefreshNodeCommand?.Execute(ViewModel.SelectedTreeNode);
                        if (evt.Source is Control control)
                        {
                            var treeviewItem = control.FindLogicalAncestorOfType<TreeViewItem>();
                            if (treeviewItem is { Focusable: true })
                            {
                                var focused = treeviewItem.Focus();
                            }
                        }
                        evt.Handled = true;
                    })
                    .DisposeWith(disposable);
```

The code finds the item just fine, but as mentioned, focused stays false.

**UPDATE:** turns out that the reason the treeview (item) loses focus, is that the container of the treeview is disabled while processing the refresh(via a binding on an IsLoading bool property on the view model). If I drop the disabling, then the focus is kept.

However, while this more or less explains the original issue, the question remains why I'm unable to focus the item.